I can sort normally using mouse, but keyboard shortcut gives error
When I select a cell range and go to Data>Sort Range>A to Z, it works perfectly!
but when I select a cell range and press Alt + D + S + A, then it gives me an error that few of my cells are merged (which they are), but those merged cells are not in the cell range I want to sort.

Wrong Shortcut
You are using the wrong keyboard shortcut.

The keyboard shortcut for sorting ascending a range by the first selected column, <x> is a column letter placeholder
ata > Sot Range > Sot Range by Column <X> (A-Z)
should be one of the following *
Alt+D R R
  
Alt+Shift+D R R

The keyboard shortcut you are using,
Alt+D S A
is for sorting (ascending) the entire sheet by the first selected column, and since it is sorting the entire sheet, any merged cells outside the selection are therefore included.



*
If you have 'Compatible spreadsheet shortcuts' enabled, you need to use Alt+Shift. If you do not, you can use either Alt+Shift or Alt.
The toggle is accessed using Ctrl+/ and under Help >Keyboard shortcuts


thank you man! I now appreciate the mouse even more!
(also again apologies, I am not used to checking replies on stackoverflow since I am new here)
